# Why after yield all([someGenerator]), another function is not called

Tags: redux, redux-saga

I try to call another function after yield all([])

When I replace call() effect with fork(), it works. I know that fork() is no-blocking effect. But assuming that all the effects are resolved (using call()), next line should be also called.

After all() effect I try to call another generator with WebSockets. Maybe it is not the best place, but I don't know why it doesn't work anyway.

````
export function* someGenerator () {
    try {
    return true
    } catch (e) {}
}

export function* watchSomeAction() {
    yield takeEvery('someAction', someGenerator )
}


export default function* rootSaga () {
    yield all([call(watchSomeAction)])

    yield call(anotherGenerator) \\ never called even when all the effects are
 resolved
}```
````

Comment: https://runkit.com/iofjuupasli/stack-57769604
It's called. Can you create runnable code that reproduces the issue?

Comment: You are right, thank you. Sorry, my mistake. I updated my example. 
I gess that I should't use takeEvery because it will never resolve. Am I right? 

It works:

````export function* watchSomeAction() {
    yield take('someAction')
    yield someGenerator()
}````